# How to handle missing elements after calling preg_split()

Tags: php, wordpress, split, custom-post-type, text-extraction

I'm working on a shortcode to display a custom post type, which mostly works. I don't control the feed this data is coming from, hence the need to split up the title based on delimiters. The problem I'm experiencing is that the variables first, second, third, and fourth can be null, and I don't know how to account for this in this context.

```
function display_custom_post_type() {
    // ... irrelevant code ...
    $title = (get_the_title ());
    $str = preg_split('(\||\[|\]|=)', $title,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print_r($title);
    $first = $str[0];
    $second = $str[1];
    $third = $str[2];
    $fourth = $str[3];
            
    $string .= '<h3 class="test-parl-title"><div>' . $first . '</div></h3>';
            
    $string .= '<h5>' . $second . ' ' . $third . ' ' . $fourth . '</h5>';
    // ... irrelevant code ...
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: This question does not include sample strings that may be encountered in `$title`.  We cannot verify answers as being correct if you do not provide sample input(s) and your exact desired output for each sample.

Comment: It is possible that we can recommend a superior regex pattern if we can see what text is being processed and how it may vary.

Comment: https://onecompiler.com/php/3ymj4bfny

Answer (score 3):

### Try some syntactic sugar

If you are running php 7.0.x or higher you can use [the null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).  It's syntatic sugar but it's very easy to read:

```
$title  = get_the_title();
$str    = preg_split( '(\||\[|\]|=)', $title, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
$first  = $str[0] ?? '';
$second = $str[1] ?? '';
$third  = $str[2] ?? '';
$fourth = $str[3] ?? '';
```

The variables are getting assigned the $str[0] if it exists and is not null, otherwise they are assigned the second argument (here, an empty string, but you can use what you want).

Here's your whole function rewritten in a slightly easier to read format (untested):

```
function display_custom_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'parl',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'pagination'     => true,
        'posts_per_page' => '10',
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'paged'          => $paged,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
            $query->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="test-parl-article">
                <img class="test-parl-icon" src="/wp-content/uploads/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Photo of Joe Blogs">
                <div class="test-parl-article-meta">
                    <?php
                    $str = preg_split( '(\||\[|\]|=)', get_the_title(), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
                    $first  = $str[0] ?? '';
                    $second = $str[1] ?? '';
                    $third  = $str[2] ?? '';
                    $fourth = $str[3] ?? '';
                    ?>
                    <h3 class="test-parl-title"><div><?php echo esc_html( $first ); ?></div></h3>
                    <h5><?php echo esc_html( "${second} ${third} ${fourth}" ); ?></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="test-parl-date"><?php the_date(); ?></div>
                <div class="test-parl-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener">View in context</a></div>
            </div>
            <article class="test-article-body"><?php the_content(); ?></article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="pagination">
        <div class="previous-page"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Posts' ); ?></div>
        <div class="next-page"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older Posts', $query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

In a comment you said that $str[0] is always populated and the others vars can be null:

```
$string .= '<h3 class="test-parl-title"><div>' . $str[0] . '</div></h3>';

unset($str[0]);

if (!empty($str) {
     $string .= '<h5>' . implode(' ', $str) . '</h5>';
}
```

I used $str[0] in h3. I deleted it and imploded whatever remained if it wasn't empty. This is shorter than using $first, $second, $third, $fourth, etc.

Comment: In practice, the regex works. It just spits out a bunch of warnings about  Undefined array keys. $first is always populated, but $second, $third, and $fourth won't always be due to the fairly random nature of the titles.

Comment: The answer still applies, count the $str array, and decide how to build your HTML further using this information.

Comment: I updated the answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if value that come from html is empty string and make for loop to transfer empty string to null

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
  if($value === ""){
      $_POST[$key] = null;
}
}
```

you can you also `isset($var);` also to check if variable have null value or undefine variable.

Comment: I've added your code in underneath the $str = preg_split, but it is still complaining about key 3 being undefined. Apparently I'm missing something.

Comment: str[3] is empty string or undefine or null value ?

Comment: The specific warning is Undefined array key

Comment: use isset(); to make sure that the key is exsist in array

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `empty` function:

```
if( $query->have_posts() ){
        while( $query->have_posts() ){
            $query->the_post();
            $string .= '<div class="test-parl-article">';
            $string .= '<img class="test-parl-icon" src="/wp-content/uploads/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Photo of Joe Blogs">';
            $string .= '<div class="test-parl-article-meta">';

            $title = (get_the_title());
            $str = preg_split('(\||\[|\]|=)', $title,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

            $string .= '<h3 class="test-parl-title"><div>' . empty($str[0]) ? '': $str[0] . '</div></h3>';

            $string .= '<h5>' . empty($str[1]) ? '' : $str[1] . ' ' . empty($str[2]) ? '' : $str[2] . ' ' . empty($str[3]) ? '' : $str[3] . '</h5>';



            $string .= '</div>';
            $string .= '<div class="test-parl-date">' . get_the_date() . '</div>';
            $string .= '<div class="test-parl-link"><a href="' . get_permalink() . 'target="_blank" rel="noopener">View in context</a></div>';
            $string .= '</div>';
            $string .= '<article class="test-article-body">' . get_the_content() . '</article>';
        }
        $string .= '</div>';
    }
```

More detail is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). Hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not easily with standard PHP functions?

```php
$elements = preg_split('(\||\[|\]|=)', $title,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$string .= '<h3 class="test-parl-title"><div>' . array_shift($elements) . '</div></h3>';
$string .= '<h5>' . implode(' ', array_filter($elements)) . '</h5>';
// EDIT: or to avoid empty h5 tags
$string .= empty($elements) ? '' : '<h5>' . implode(' ', array_filter($elements)) . '</h5>';
```